# next config js not working after adding webpack

Tags: webpack, next.js, loader

i tried to change the next.config.js file to use a new loader but it always seems to fail, here is my next.config.js:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      // regex for the files that are problematic
      test: "/\.js$/",
      use: "unlazy-loader",
    });

    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

it returns Error [ValidationError]: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

Comment: Replace your `use` with `loader` in `next.config.js`